# Using ServiceStack with a ServiceReferenceClient

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to call ServiceStack service from a console app with a service reference client (generated after using Add Service Reference in VS 2010).

I looked at the sample at [github](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Extras/blob/master/doc/UsageExamples/UsingServiceReferenceClient.cs) but was unable to create a similar client code.

My objective is to provide a set of services with a simple API that can be called by a .NET client as easy as possible. Ideally, client should not need any knowledge of ServiceStack to call the services.

My questions are:

- How should I create request if the service does not need any parameters?
- How can I resolve proxy.Properties?

Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/3361477)

Comment: Looks like proxy.Properties is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SOAP/WSDL's `Add Service Reference` but you should be mindful of [SOAP's Limitations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support).

Although the [current recommendations for client libraries](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Clients-overview) is to use your preferred choice of ServiceStack's built-in generic service clients.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working, updated [gist](https://gist.github.com/3361477) Removed properties, version, request